# Error 400 Nothing to geocode with Openweathermap API

Tags: openweathermap

I am trying to use openweathermap for my python app but there is a problem. I do a simple request to this link: `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,fr&appid=[My Key]`

I get an error 400 with the message `Nothing to geocode`.

Do you know what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that it's giving you an error is because you're asking the API for data on London, France (`q=London,fr`). The `fr` part is the country code.

All you have to do is change `fr` to `uk` and you should be set! The link would be http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=[yourID]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the **lat** and **lon** after the URL and then add your **API key**, then it will work:

https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&APPID=YOUR_API_KEY

Answer (score -1):

You may also input the lat and long of the location and try to build again.

> api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139
>   Like This ^

Comment: did not work for me and not found in the documentation as well